# Who exactly is that creature is Rey referring to?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

> Kylo Ren: You still want to kill me.
>
> Rey: That happens when you're being hunted...by a **creature** in a mask.

Who exactly is that creature is Rey referring to?

Comment: Seems pretty obvious that she's referring to Kylo Ren himself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**CONTEXT!**

It's pretty clear when you [watch the scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlT-sJLfCPU) what Rey is referring to. Let's add the context to the lines:

> 0:27 *Kylo, wearing a MASK, tilts his head to one side and speaks in a
> gentle, questioning voice.*
>
> 0:28 Kylo Ren: **You still want to kill me**.
>
> 0:30 *Rey responds in a matter of fact tone.*
>
> 0:31 Rey: **That happens when you're being hunted by a creature in a
> mask**.
>
> 0:35 *Kylo reflects on Rey's statement.*
>
> 0:36 *Kylo raises his hands to the sides of his mask.*
>
> 0:37 *Sound effect of mask being disengaged along with visual cue.*
>
> 0:39 *Kylo removes the mask while rising to a standing position.*
>
> 0:40 *Kylo reveals his face to Rey. He is no longer the "creature in a
> mask" but a person.*

It's pretty clear from context that Rey is referring to Kylo as the "creature in a mask" and that Kylo recognises this by removing his mask.